# Python on Chromebook - matplotlib plot window partially displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, debian, chromebook

I'm running python 3.5.3 64bit on my Google PixelBook with VSCode as my IDE. I'm following an online tutorial and have the following script:

```py
import  matplotlib.pyplot   as  plt
# import    numpy       as  np
# import    pandas      as  pd

x   =   [1,2,3]
y   =   [2,4,6]

plt.plot(x,y)
print(plt.get_backend())
# plt.savefig('matplotlib/image.svg')
plt.show()
```

I've tried doing some troubleshooting myself.
The backend is 'TkAgg'. The plot does show in a window but only part is shown

[image: 1]

The window appears to work - I can see coordinates etc as I mouse over.
The saved plot also looks OK so assuming it's a tkinter issue rather than mathplotlib?

What have I missed?